# How to "Highlight Selected Row" with custom color based on condition' in primefaces

Tags: datatable, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have give `rowStyle` based on condition. This datatable also has selection (check-box) option.

```
rowStyleClass="#{condt ? myStyle : null}"
```

I would like to retain the custom style that is applied on the row, even when it is selected (i.e., check-box is checked). By default, when the row is selected it is highlighted in yellow irrespective of the style applied.

CSS:

```
 .ui-datatable .ui-state-highlight {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: yellow !important;
    }
    .myStyle  {
        background-image: none;
        background-color: red !important;
    }
```

Can I retain the `rowStyle` already applied even when check-box is selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-default-primefaces-css-with-custom-styles)

Answer (score 0):

To retain the custom color when row(the check-box) is selected, I used below CSS

```
.ui-datatable .ui-state-highlight.myStyle {
            background-image: none;
            background-color: red !important;
        }
```

By doing so, the selected row that had no style applied will be highlighted in yellow, however if the row which has custom style applied is selected, then only the check-box will be checked and the highlight color of the row will not change to yellow.

Comment: The duplicate contains the answer.